# Cannot feed value of shape (50,) for Tensor 'upper/input/y:0', which has shape '(?, 5)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50,) for Tensor 'upper/input/y:0', which has shape '(?, 5)'
```

Here 50 is batch size.
My data size is (2930,2,128,128) and label size is (2930,)
I am unable to understand about the mismatch of shape.
Code drives 2 channels (128,128) separately and merges later. my labels contains 5 classes(0,1,2,3,4).

```
# read  data
def load_data(filename):
try:
    data = np.load(filename)
    ds = DataSet(data['img'], data['code']) // img=[2930,2,128,128]
except:                              //code = [2930,] single vector
    print("Can not find data file")
    ds = None
finally:
    return ds

# help functions to build graph
def weight_variable(shape):
initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
return tf.Variable(initial)


def conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]):
return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=strides, padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],     padding='SAME')


def single_net(RES):
with tf.name_scope('input'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, RES, RES], name='x')
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,5], name='y')

    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, RES, RES, 1], name='x-reshape')

# first layer
with tf.name_scope('layer1'):
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 16])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([16])

    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
    # [-1, 64, 64, 16]

# second layer
with tf.name_scope('layer2'):
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 16, 32])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([32])

    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
    # [-1, 16, 16, 32]

with tf.name_scope('layer3'):
    W_conv3 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 64])
    b_conv3 = bias_variable([64])

    h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]) + b_conv3)
    h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3)
    # [-1, 4, 4, 64] = [-1, 1024]

# dense layer
with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([4 * 4 * 64, 512])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([512])

    h_pool3_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool3, [-1, 4 * 4 * 64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool3_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
    # [-1, 512]

return x, y_, h_fc1


class DLSpMVModel(object):
    def __init__(self, train_data, test_data):

        self.RES = 0
        self.mean = 0
        self.std = 1

        self.train = load_data(train_data)
        if self.train:
            print(self.train.images.shape, self.train.labels.shape)
            self.RES = self.train.images.shape[-1] # 128
            self.mean = np.mean(self.train.images[:,0,:,:], axis=0)
            self.std = np.std(self.train.images[:,0,:,:], axis=0)

        self.test = load_data(test_data)
        if self.test and self.RES == 0:
            print(self.test.images.shape, self.test.labels.shape)
            self.RES = self.test.images.shape[-1] # 128

        self.STEPS = 10000


    def build_graph(self):
        pass


    def training(self):

        print("Model is in training mode")
        assert self.train is not None and self.test is not None, "data not loaded"

        with tf.name_scope('upper'):
            x, y_, h_fc1_upper = single_net(self.RES)

        with tf.name_scope('lower'):
            x2, y2_, h_fc1_lower = single_net(self.RES)

        h_fc1 = tf.concat([h_fc1_upper, h_fc1_lower], axis=1)
        # [-1, 512 * 2]

        with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
            keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
            h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

        with tf.name_scope('out'):
            W_fc2 = weight_variable([512 * 2, 5])
            b_fc2 = bias_variable([5])

            y_conv = tf.add(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2), b_fc2, name='y_conv_restore')

        with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
            cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                    labels=y_, logits=y_conv)  # takes unnormalized output
            )

        with tf.name_scope('train'):
            train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name='acc_to_restore')
            tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)

        merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

        saver = tf.train.Saver()  # traditional saving api

        # train the model
        with tf.Session() as sess:

            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            for i in range(self.STEPS):
                batch = self.train.next_batch(50)
                if i % 100 == 0:
                    train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch[0][:,0,:,:], y_: batch[1], x2: batch[0][:,1,:,:], y2_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
                    print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
                else:
                    _ = sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0][:,0,:,:], y_: batch[1], x2: batch[0][:,1,:,:], y2_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
            # test
            print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: self.test.images[:,0,:,:], y_: self.test.labels, x2: self.test.images[:,1,:,:], y2_: self.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

            # save model and checkpoint
            save_path = saver.save(sess, os.path.join(ROOTDIR, "dnnspmv/model/spmv/model-{}.ckpt".format(self.STEPS)))
            print("Model saved in file %s" % save_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just reshape the labels

```
labels = np.reshape(labels, (-1, 1))
```

and this should do the trick.